# How to efficiently type in a pair of XML tags in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, editing, hotkeys, xml, key-binding

How to efficiently type in a pair of XML tags such as `<tag></tag>` in Emacs?

I am hoping some sort of auto-complete behavior.

Comment: I think the most effective way is to use snippets like in the answers to your other question: http://superuser.com/questions/394802/how-to-define-a-shortcut-key-combination-to-insert-tag-tag-in-emacs. Also, you might want to vote on useful answers to your questions to show appreciation. You have asked 22 question but only voted on 6 answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to your .emacs file.

```
;; associate xml, xsd, etc with nxml-mode
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist (cons (concat "\\." (regexp-opt '("xml" "xsd" "rng" "xslt" "xsl") t) "\\'") 'nxml-mode))
```

set the automplete flag to true

```
(setq nxml-slash-auto-complete-flag t)
```

Comment: This will complete the appropriate close tag after you type `</`

Comment: How to use this when I am inserting pairs of tags in a file that's not XML, XSD, etc.?

Comment: switch the nxml mode. M-x nmxl-mode

Comment: This basically works. One drawback of this is that when I need to insert pairs of tags frequently in a markdown file for which I use `markdown-mode`, I need to switch between `markdown-mode` and `nxml-mode` frequently. Any suggestion?

Comment: Emacs does not support multiple major modes. So you should switch between modes. Define a shortcut which does it quickly

Comment: How to define a shortcut to switch between the two modes?