# How to define a shortcut (key combination) to insert "<tag></tag>" in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, shortcuts, key-binding, elisp

I want to define a shortcut to enter XML tag pairs.  Pressing key combination `key1`-`key2` which should prompt for entering a tag name, .e.g. "foo", and automatically insert "`<foo></foo>`". How to do that?

Ideally I'd like the cursor to be automatically moved to be after the first `>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [YASnippet](http://capitaomorte.github.com/yasnippet/) in xml-mode it already contains a snippet for the functionality you ask for.

Enter the following

```
tag
```

press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and choose `<tag>...</tag>` for an inline XML tag or `<tag>\n...\n</tag>` for a tag on its own line and what you entered turns into

```
<tag></tag>
```

or

```
<tag>

</tag>
```

respectively. As what you have entered turns into either the name for the opening tag is marked and you can enter whatever tag name you want and it will copied to the closing tag too. When you are done entering the tag name you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and the cursor is placed between the tags so that you can enter content to the tag. When you are done entering content in the tag you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> again to place the cursor after the closing tag.

Note that if you want to customize the behavior of these snippet it is easy. Use the YASnippet menu to find the snippets in question and then edit them to fit your needs.

To get the said snippets in any other mode you can create them for that mode by doing as follows:

1. Add the following to your .emacs:

   ```
   (setq yas/root-directory "~/.emacs.d/mysnippets"); Develop and keep personal snippets under ~/emacs.d/mysnippets
   (yas/load-directory yas/root-directory); Load the snippets
   ```

   If you prefer to keep your snippet in another directory go ahead and choose another.
2. Enter the mode you want the snippets in.
3. Do <kbd>M-x</kbd> `yas/new-snippet`.
4. Enter the name `tag.1l`
5. You will now get a chance to edit the snippet. Mark everything by doing <kbd>C-x h</kbd>, then kill it by <kbd>C-w</kbd>.
6. You will now have an empty snippet. Paste the following into it *and make sure the snippet ends after* `$0` *and not on a new line*:

   ```
   #name: <tag>...</tag>
   #key: tag
   # --
   <${1:tag}>$2</$1>$0
   ```
7. Do <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> to save and load the snippet.
8. Do step 3 to 7 but instead use the name `tag.2l` and instead paste in the following:

   ```
   #name: <tag> \n...\n</tag>
   #key: tag
   # --
   <${1:tag}>
     $2
   </$1>$0
   ```

Note that the key yasnippet uses for expansion, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, is bound to another function in markdown-mode by default. Thus you either have to use a fix such as http://calas.github.com/2009/11/20/using-yasnippets-in-markdown-mode.html or bind `yas/expand` to a key of your preference.

The following animation shows how the first snippet works:

[image: Animation of the snippet <${1:tag}>$2</$1>$0]

Comment: Your suggested trick works except that every time when I need to enter xml-mode first.  How to make that more easy? How to define a short cut so I don't need to manually enter xml-mode?

Comment: @duperuser You may not want to enable that snippet for all modes but just for some modes. What modes do you want to use it in? Maybe you need a more effective way to enter xml-mode instead?

Comment: I want to quickly insert pair of `<tag></tag>` when editting a markdown file in `markdown-mode`.

Comment: @duperuser I have added instructions for how to use it in markdown-mode.

Comment: This gets closer to what I want, but not perfectly.  I want to be able to insert `<foobar>` first, strike `Tab`, and have `</foobar>` automatically inserted, and cursor moved in front of `</`.  Here `foobar` may be any sequence of letters.

Comment: Never mind.  This is good enough.  I didn't realize the cursor automatically moves to after the first `<` and lets you type the tag name and automatically sync the closing tag.  Perfect!

Comment: Actually, one more issue: for `tag.2l`.  I'd like four white space characters inserted on the second line, i.e. before the supposedly starting point for the value between the tags, there should be four spaces inserted.

Comment: @duperuser If you want four spaces in tag.2l: 1) Enter markdown-mode, 2) `M-x yas/find-snippets`, 3) Choose tag.2l, 4) Make it so that there is four spaces before `$2`, 4) `C-c C-c` to save and load the snippet.

Comment: @duperuser Note that you should up-vote useful answers to show appreciation (not doing so can be considered rude). I can see that you have accepted some answers without up-voting them. For details see [faq#howtoask].

Comment: Why it needs funky file name extension such as `1l` and `2l`?

Comment: @duperuser I copied the file names from the snippets for xml-mode. I think `1l` refers to one-line in that the tag only spans one line and that `2l` refers to two-line in that the tags take one line each, i.e. two lines.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible and should be easy to write that.

But I think what you are after is snippet/skeletons. Please checkout [yasnippet](https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet). Its basically a template system easily extensible to your needs

Comment: I'm using `yasnippet` in LaTeX, should be very helpful for this case as well.